# Reat Native - position absolute not show on top of View

Tags: react-native

I use React Native 0.55, and I want to display a kind of icon on top of a , like this : http://b3.ms/qpknagGre9BR

For now, I use this :

```
<View style={styles.cardContainer}>
    <Image source={iconPlayers} style={styles.iconTop} />
    <View style={styles.cardBox}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.txtTitle}>
                My title
            </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

And my styles :

```
cardBox: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    padding: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderColor: "#DDD",
    elevation: 4,
    paddingTop: 40,
},
cardContainer: {
    marginTop: 40,
},
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
txtTitle: {
    color: "#000",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
},
iconTop: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    zIndex: 999,
    position: "absolute",
    top: -30,
    elevation: 4,
    alignSelf: "center",
},
```

It's crazy because now it works, but I have a problem, I can't put `elevation: 4` on styles for an `<Image />` element, I have a **Warning**.

If I remove the `elevation: 4,` of my styles, the image is shown behind the **cardBox**.

How can I achieve what I want without any warning ... ? Thanks.

** **EDIT** **

I wrapper the `<Image />` in a `<View />`, and I put `elevation` property to the wrapper, and it works.

I thought `elevation` was for boxShadow for android, but it impacts the zIndex.

Comment: It would be better to wrap the `Image` in a `View` and apply container styles to it.

Comment: I tried it, but the result is the same, the `<View><Image /></View>` is behind the other `<View>`

Comment: What warning are you getting?

Comment: The warning is about the `elevation` property applied to `<Image />` element

Comment: Please be specific, exactly what the warning says.

Comment: You just can't apply `elevation` property to an `<Image />`, how can I be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying your code in snack expo, which uses the latest react-native version (55.4). There is no warning in applying elevation to Image property, it just works fine and the image is also above the card. If your react-native version gives warning just wrap it in a View and apply elevation to that View. Also, remember zIndex gets affected by your Views elevation (only Android). Since you have applied elevation: 4 to card box, you must give elevation >= 4 for your Image component else it will draw beneath the card box.

snack example: https://snack.expo.io/B14UPA9Bm

You can also avoid Zindex by changing the order of components,

```
// Render the image component after your card box this way you can avoid setting the zIndex
<View style={styles.cardContainer}>
    <View style={styles.cardBox}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.txtTitle}>
                My title
            </Text>
        </View>
    </View>
    <Image source={iconPlayers} style={styles.iconTop} />
</View>

cardBox: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    padding: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderColor: "#DDD",
    elevation: 4,
    paddingTop: 40,
},
cardContainer: {
    marginTop: 40,
},
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
txtTitle: {
    color: "#000",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
},
iconTop: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    //zIndex: 999, not required now
    position: "absolute",
    top: -30,
    elevation: 4,
    alignSelf: "center",
},
```

Check and tell if it works in Android and iOS. thanks

Comment: Thanks for you time, maybe in snack warnings are hidden. I used a wrapper and I use elevation property on the wrapper, it worked